# Crear animación para desplegar una fila de una tabla

Tags: javascript, css, html5, scss

He conseguido que funcione la animación pero se crea antes el espacio de la fila y después baja el contenido.

```js
const toggle = e => {
  document.querySelector(".hide")
    ? (document.querySelector(".hide").className = "")
    : (document.querySelector("#hideMe").className = "hide");
};

document.getElementById("toggle").addEventListener("click", toggle);
```

```css
body {
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

tr {
  display: table-row;
  animation: slide-down 0.3s ease-out;
}

.hide {
  display: none;
}

@keyframes slide-down {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transform: translateY(-100%);
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
    -webkit-transform: translateY(0);
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
 <title>Sandbox</title>
 <meta charset="UTF-8" />
</head>

<body>
 <table border="1">
  <tr id="toggle">
   <td>test</td>
   <td>test</td>
  </tr>
  <tr id="hideMe" class="hide">
   <td>test</td>
   <td>test</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td>test</td>
   <td>test</td>
  </tr>
 </table>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Las filas (`tr`) de las tablas (`table`) no aceptan una altura menor a la de su contenido, y es por esto que no podemos animar el `height`.

### Solución:

Podemos agregar un `div` en cada celda (`td`) al cual modificaremos su `max-height` con un valor lo suficientemente grande para mostrar el contenido de mayor altura.

#### Ejemplo

```js
const toggle = e => {
  document.querySelector(".hide") ?
    (document.querySelector(".hide").className = "") :
    (document.querySelector("#hideMe").className = "hide");
};

document.getElementById("toggle").addEventListener("click", toggle);
```

```css
body {
  font-family: sans-serif;
}
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
}
tr,td {
  padding: 0;
}
tr {
  opacity: 1;
  transition: opacity 0.6s;
}
tr td div {
  max-height: 100px;
  padding: 4px;
  opacity: 1;
  transition: max-height 0.6s, padding 0.6s, opacity 0.6s;
}
tr.hide td div {
  opacity: 0;
}
tr.hide td div {
  max-height: 0;
  padding: 0 4px;
  opacity: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<table border="1">
  <tr id="toggle">
    <td><div>test</div></td>
    <td><div>test</div></td>
  </tr>
  <tr id="hideMe" class="hide">
    <td><div>test</div></td>
    <td><div>test</div></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><div>test</div></td>
    <td><div>test</div></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

### Créditos:

- [Respuesta original de SOen](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37376274/3791844)